# Run before block once with RSpec 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec3, ruby-on-rails-6

I can't find a way around this.

This is my test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe V1::UsersController do

  describe '#create' do
    let(:post_params) do
      {
        first_nm: Faker::Name.first_name,
        last_nm: Faker::Name.last_name ,
        password: "test123456",
        password_confirmation: "test123456",
        email_address: Faker::Internet.email
      }
    end

    before do
      post :create, params: post_params
    end

    context 'successful create' do
      subject(:user) { User.find_by_email(post_params[:email_address]) }

      it 'persists the user' do
        expect(user).not_to be_nil
      end

      it 'user data is correct' do
        post_params.except(:password, :password_confirmation).each do |k, v|
          expect(user.send(k)).to eq(v)
        end
      end

      it 'returns responsde code of 201' do
        expect(response.status).to eq(201)
      end

    end
  end
end
```

I only want this controller to be hit once. However, I can't seem to get that to work.

I have tried setting `before(:context)` and I get an error

```
RuntimeError:
       let declaration `post_params` accessed in a `before(:context)` hook at:

       `let` and `subject` declarations are not intended to be called
       in a `before(:context)` hook, as they exist to define state that
       is reset between each example, while `before(:context)` exists to
       define state that is shared across examples in an example group.
```

I don't want multiple users to be persisted for such a simple test. I also dont want to be hitting the api for every example.

I want the `before` block to run once. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you explain how changing the `before` to `let` would work?

Comment: Nevermind, that won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message states, `let` and `subject` are specifically for managing per-example state.  But `before(:context)`/`before(:all)` hooks get run outside the scope of any specific example, so they are fundamentally incompatible.  If you want to use `before(:context)`, you can't reference any `let` definitions from the hook.  You'll have to manage the `post_params` state yourself without using `let`.  Here's a simple way to do that:

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe V1::UsersController do
  describe '#create' do
    before(:context) do
      @post_params = {
        first_nm: Faker::Name.first_name,
        last_nm: Faker::Name.last_name ,
        password: "test123456",
        password_confirmation: "test123456",
        email_address: Faker::Internet.email
      }

      post :create, params: @post_params
    end

    context 'successful create' do
      subject(:user) { User.find_by_email(@post_params[:email_address]) }

      it 'persists the user' do
        expect(user).not_to be_nil
      end

      it 'user data is correct' do
        @post_params.except(:password, :password_confirmation).each do |k, v|
          expect(user.send(k)).to eq(v)
        end
      end

      it 'returns responsde code of 201' do
        expect(response.status).to eq(201)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

That should solve your problem; however it's not the approach I would recommend.  Instead, I recommend you use the [`aggregate_failures`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/expectation-framework-integration/aggregating-failures) feature of RSpec 3.3+ and put all of this in a single example, like so:

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe V1::UsersController do
  describe '#create' do
    let(:post_params) do
      {
        first_nm: Faker::Name.first_name,
        last_nm: Faker::Name.last_name ,
        password: "test123456",
        password_confirmation: "test123456",
        email_address: Faker::Internet.email
      }
    end

    it 'successfully creates a user with the requested params', :aggregate_failures do
      post :create, params: post_params

      expect(response.status).to eq(201)
      user = User.find_by_email(post_params[:email_address])
      expect(user).not_to be_nil

      post_params.except(:password, :password_confirmation).each do |k, v|
        expect(user.send(k)).to eq(v)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`aggregate_failures` gives you a failure report indicating each expectation that failed (rather than just the first one like normal), just like if you had separated it into 3 separate examples, while allowing you to actually make it a single example.  This allows you to incapsulate the action you are testing in a single example, allowing you to only perform the action once like you want.  In a lot of ways, this fits better with the per-example state sandboxing provided by RSpec's features like `before` hooks, `let` declarations and the DB-transaction rollback provided by rspec-rails, anyway.  And

I like the `aggregate_failures` feature so much that I tend to configure RSpec to automatically apply it to every example in `spec_helper.rb`:

```rb
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.define_derived_metadata do |meta|
    meta[:aggregate_failures] = true unless meta.key?(:aggregate_failures)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `before(:all)`, which will run once before all the cases. 
There is similar `after(:all)` as well.

Interestingly, the `before` is basically a shorter way of saying `before(:each)` (which IMO makes more sense).

Comment: that doesn't work either :| , only solution I have so far is to just have one example. Also, RSpec 3 only has the  `:all` option for backwards compatibility

Comment: Okay, your error is something else than I thought. So basically, the params that you define are lazily loaded. It means, they are initialized when they are used for the first time in the `it` block. Hence, you cannot use any param you declared as `let` in `before` since they are not yet initialized.  You should declared `post_params` without `let`